# How to Implement KMP string seaching algorithm on my listview ...?

Tags: java, android, algorithm

I have a listview and I want to add a search in listview using the algorithm KMP

How to Implement on my listView.

```
@Override
public  void  onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_istilah);
    autoTv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.AutoTV);

    db = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(this);

   setData();

    autoTv.addTextChangedListener(this);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

}

private  void  setData()
{
    listKamus = db.getAllKamus();

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Kamus>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, listKamus);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

Comment: I know how to implement KMP, but I don't know how it relates to Android list views. Can you be more specific, please?

Comment: In listview i have data from database , on above listview i want to string searching  in edittext using Kmp algorithm.